# ¿Como puedo hacer para separar las letras de varias palabras de una cadena?

Tags: javascript

Tengo las palabras 'hola' y 'maria', y no se como hacer para dividir ambas palabras en letras. lo he intentado con .split() y con .slice() y no me funciona. ¿Alguien me ayuda? Gracias.

Las palabras se tienen que dividir por separado.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Segundo Algoritmo</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h3 id="om">hola maria</h3>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h3>Lista Ordenada Alfabéticamente:</h3>
            <p id="alfa"></p>
            <br>
        <h3>Lista Ordenada por Longitud:</h3>
            <p id="long"></p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p id="ter"></p>
</body>
<script>
    var primero = document.getElementById('om').innerText.split(' ');
    var segundo = primero.slice();
    var terc = primero.length();
    var tercero = terc.split();

    primero.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
    });

    segundo.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.length > b.length) {
        return 1; 
    }
    if (a.length < b.length) { 
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
    });
    
    


    document.getElementById("alfa").innerHTML = primero.join(', ');
    document.getElementById("long").innerHTML = segundo.join(', ');
    document.getElementById("ter").innerHTML = tercero;
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

el error que estabas cometiendo es el querer hacer el `.split()` sin pasarle un argumento, en este caso para separar cada letra tendria que ser `.split("")` :

```js
var el = document.getElementById("nombre");
var res = document.getElementById("resultado");
var res2 = document.getElementById("resultado2");
var separado = el.textContent.split("");

res.textContent = separado.join(",");

//si queres sacar los espacios vacios : 
var texto = el.textContent.replace(/\s/gm, "").split("");
res2.textContent = texto;
```

```html
<div id="nombre">
  hola maria
</div>
<div id="resultado">
  
</div>
<div id="resultado2">
  
</div>
```

lo mismo pasaba con el `slice()` ya que le tenes que pasar como argumento : donde comenzar y donde terminar. si es letra por letra, empieza en `i-1` y termina en `i`:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("nombre");
var res = document.getElementById("resultado");
var res2 = document.getElementById("resultado2");
var separado = [];
var separado2 = [];

for (i = 0; i < el.textContent.length ; i++) {
     separado.push(el.textContent.slice(i-1,i));
}

res.textContent = separado.join(",");

//si queres sacar los espacios vacios : 
var texto = el.textContent.replace(/\s/gm, "");
for (i = 1; i <= texto.length ; i++) {
     separado2.push(texto.slice(i-1,i));
}
res2.textContent = separado2.join(",");
```

```html
<div id="nombre">
  hola maria
</div>
<div id="resultado">
  
</div>
<div id="resultado2">
  
</div>
```

espero que te sea de ayuda

Answer (score 5):

Para separar un tipo String en caracteres puedes usar el método `split`, al cual le pasas como argumento un carácter nulo (`''`).

Aunque no se exactamente cómo deseas mostrar la salida, te pongo este código de ejemplo.

Nótese que el carácter de espacio también lo incluye en el `Array` de caracteres.

```html
<h3 id="om">hola maria</h3>
<br>
<br>
<h3>Separada por letras:</h3>
<p id="alfa"></p>
<br>
<script>
    var letras = document.getElementById('om').innerText.split('');
    var lista = letras.join(', ');
    document.getElementById("alfa").innerHTML = letras.join(', ');
</script>
</html>
```

**Nota**

Si bien este método separa los caracteres de un *String*, habrá que tener en cuenta que no funciona con caracteres [*UNICODE*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

Dado que no especificas el uso, ésta sería una solución parcial. Sólo si sabes que tus caracteres en el `String` son todos [*ASCII*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), entonces el método es 100% efectivo.